# how can i add dynamic labels and text input field in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dynamic

I'm trying to ask user how many variables he like to enter then my program should create label for each variable and input field for each variable.
I need help to figure out how can I generate running time label fields and input fields in Xcode. I have a solution which asks values for each variable. But I badly need to use dynamic label fields and input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this in code, it is quite straight forward.

```
UILabel *dynamicLabel = [UILabel alloc] initWithFramee:CGRectMake(0,0,50,30)];
[self.view addSubview:dynamicLabel];

UITextField *dynamicTextFeild = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:dynamicTextFeild];
```

Edit for desired layout.

Hope this helps.